# sequelize working with MySQL doesn't returns id create with a function called in a before insert trigger

Tags: javascript, mysql, orm, triggers, sequelize.js

i use sequelize with mysql and in my table 'users' i have a before_insert trigger that calls a function that create my row's id.

when i run:

```
userObj = {someField: 'some1', someOtherfield: 'some2'};   // Obviously without id
 db.User.create(userObj, { fields: Object.keys(userObj), transaction: t })
 .then( (newUser) => {
    // HERE
    newUser['id'] = null; // BUT ON MY TABLE it has a valid value
 });
```

so i have correct entry on my id but sequelize returns null.

Comment: can you post the code for the before_insert trigger?

Comment: @BenPolge

this is the trigger :
  SET new.id = stringify_bigint(nextval('users')), new.seed =   stringify_bigint(random_int())

stringify_bigint(A) e nextval(B) are 2 stored procedure that:
A) take in input a bigint value and returns an alphanumeric string ( length 6 )
B) simulate PG nextval and return the next int value

Comment: @BenPolge the problem is that MySQL doesn't support RETURNING like PG  ( https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5388 )